# Merging GeoTiffs with GDAL causes grid-like artifacts?

Tags: gdal, aster, gdal-merge, gdalbuildvrt, gdal-contour

I'm processing ASTER DEM tiles, merging them into larger blocks (to minimize visible tile edges) and importing the contours into a postgis database. Workflow:

```
gdal_merge.py -of GTiff -o merged.tif tile1.tif tile2.tif
gdal_contour -i 10 -a ele -snodata -9999 merged.tif contours.shp
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL -nln srtm4 -append -t_srs 'EPSG:3785' contours.shp
```

For some reason the resulting "merged" contours have grid-like artifacts:

[image]

When I skip the merge step and process the same two GeoTiffs separately, there are no artifacts. I've tried merging with `gdalbuildvrt` and got the same grid effect.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a projection issue. Prior to merging, I'm reprojecting the tiles from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3785. When this is done after the merge no problems occur.

Comment: Similar with [How to remove strange gdaldem hillshade artifacts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137290/19460)