# Hillshade output looking grided when zooming in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hillshade

I have mosaic raster files into a new raster and then running hillshade in ArcGIS and I was wondering why do I get this gridded texture when zooming in and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the answer of this question: [What is the source of horizontal and vertical striping in USGS DEMs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108957/63384)

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140026/getting-strange-grid-artifacts-when-creating-hillshades-using-gdaldem/140062#140062 ?